# Print a single character of a C string at a time

Tags: c, string

I have a variable: `char *string`
and a `for` loop with `int i=0` to `len(string)`.

Inside the loop, it prints `&string[i]`.

Trying to get it to show only a *single* character,
but if I have a string "red",
it would print:

```
red
ed
d
```

Comment: Show your code that you're using.  Consider `putchar(string[i])` and `printf("%c", string[i]);` — note that neither of these uses an `&`.  Or use `printf("%.1s", &string[i]);` — which does use `&`.

Comment: Use `%c`.  And show some code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a character with `printf()`, you need to use the appropriate format specifier, `%c`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
  strcpy(string, "red");
  for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i)
  {
    printf("%c\n", string[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
r
e
d
```

As @jonathanLeffler commented, `putchar(string[i]);` would do the trick as well.

---

In your attempt, what went wrong is this line<sup>*</sup>:

```
printf("%s\n", &string[i]);
```

which, because of the format specifier `%s` for strings, it will print the whole string until its end (NULL terminator is met), starting from the `i`-the character.

---

<sub>Reversed engineered from the sample output of yours and post.</sub>